# sed remove anchor from text on specific href

Tags: html, sed

I need to **remove anchor** in an HTML file, but only those with `href` containing `todaycycling.com/tag`.

*What I do have:*

```
<strong>Un Allemand peut en cacher un autre. Après Marcel Kittel, c\'est <a href=\"http://todaycycling.com/tag/andre-greipel\">André Greipel</a> qui a imposé sa pointe de vitesse à l\'issue de la cinquième étape du <a href=\"/tour-ditalie/\">Tour d\'Italie</a>. Dans une arrivée en faux plat montant, le sprinteur de la formation <a href=\"http://todaycycling.com/tag/lotto-soudal\">Lotto Soudal</a> a produit un intense effort pour aller chercher la victoire devant Arnaud Démare (FDJ), encore deuxième, et Sonny Colbrelli (Bardiani-CSF).
```

*What I am willing to have:*

```
<strong>Un Allemand peut en cacher un autre. Après Marcel Kittel, c\'est André Greipel qui a imposé sa pointe de vitesse à l\'issue de la cinquième étape du <a href=\"/tour-ditalie/\">Tour d\'Italie</a>. Dans une arrivée en faux plat montant, le sprinteur de la formation Lotto Soudal a produit un intense effort pour aller chercher la victoire devant Arnaud Démare (FDJ), encore deuxième, et Sonny Colbrelli (Bardiani-CSF).
```

*What I have tried so far:*

```
sed 's|<a [^>]*todaycycling\.com\/tag\/[^>]*>\([^>]*\)</a>|\1|Ig' old.html > new.html
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were really close from the result, you can use the following `sed` command for this purpose:

```
sed 's@<a\s\+href\s*=\s*\\"http://todaycycling\.com/[^>]*>\([^<]*\)</a>@\1@g' tourDeFrance.txt
```

**output:**

```
<strong>Un Allemand peut en cacher un autre. Après Marcel Kittel, c\'est André Greipel qui a imposé sa pointe de vitesse à l\'issue de la cinquième étape du <a href=\"/tour-ditalie/\">Tour d\'Italie</a>. Dans une arrivée en faux plat montant, le sprinteur de la formation Lotto Soudal a produit un intense effort pour aller chercher la victoire devant Arnaud Démare (FDJ), encore deuxième, et Sonny Colbrelli (Bardiani-CSF).
```

Comment: It works like a charm, thank you very much! Can you explain please: `@`, `[^>]*`, `[^<]*`, `\s` ?

Comment: sure: you can choose sed delimiter and I choose `@` for readability instead of `/` then the `[^>]` means all char except the `>` in order to expend the url until the closing `>` then you have the same with `[^<]` to get only the text between html tags and reuse it in the backreference the `\s` means space char and is used in case you have spaces around the `=` etc

Comment: I did not understand everything but it is ok to me! I modified the regex to match my need and target `tag` as follow `sed 's@<a\s\+href\s*=\s*\\"http://todaycycling\.com/tag[^>]*>\([^<]*\)</a>@\1@g'`. But it does NOT replace every `http://todaycycling.com/tag/...` URLs, any clue ? :-)